# What is this Norwegian shouting?

Tags: quotes, language-explanation, the-thing-2011

In this clip from the film *The Thing* (2011), Sander Halvorsen's speech is interrupted by a bearded guy (Lars?) who stands up and shouts something in Norwegian. I gather he says something to the effect of "we found an alien", but I'm having trouble making out his exact words.

**What does he say (in Norwegian), and what's the best English translation?**

Comment: The last word sounds like "skål", which means "cheers" (or, I guess "let's drink")

Comment: @WadCheber That second edit of yours could be something for an answer maybe?

Comment: I'd say he's shouting words

Comment: For the rest of this movie, if you wanna understand what the Norwegians are saying, the subtitles are very poor, giving totally wrong meanings in a lot of cases. I have clarified it here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125987/64504

Comment: @JasonBaker "Skål" litterally means "bowl." I guess they used to drink out of bowls back in the days :) Or maybe the words or "glass"/"cup" and "bowl" were the same.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

He says "Vi har funnet et jævla romvesen! Skål!".
An accurate translation would be something along the lines of "We've found a fu**ing alien! Cheers!".

Some interesting facts:

- The word "romvesen" does not literally translate to "alien". An alien refers to anything that does not belong or is not native, like a mexican in Norway. However, norwegians use the term "fremmed" (strange/stranger) or "utlending" (foreigner) to describe people. "Romvesen" literally means "**space creature**" ("rom" + "vesen", extra-terrestrial being), and this is why "alien" isn't a perfect translation - but it is likely that any and all norwegians would translate "romvesen" to "alien".
- The man is speaking a dialect. Some words are pronounced in a strange way, and this is probably why people are having a hard time separating each word.
- The term "jævla" is a pretty strong curse word, which is a reference to the devil ("djevel" -> "jævel").
- The norwegian letter "æ" is pronounced just like the A-sound in "sad" or "handicapped". If you look closely, the "æ"-letter is acutally just an A and an E put together.
- The norwegian letter "å" is pronounced just like the OU-sound in "four" as well as the O-sound in "for".

Comment: Velkommen til Stack Exchange! :-) Excellent answer; I was hoping to attract some 'experts' (i.e. Norwegians) for this one. Let's teach these Stack Exchangers something about Norwegian!

Comment: I would perhaps move the "fucking" in the English translation, rendering it as "We've fucking found an alien!". Translation is not an exact science, but if the sentence didn't mention an alien at all, it would probably be rendered, in English, as "We fucking found it!", not "We found the fucking thing!"; i.e. the expletive is related to the difficulty of finding the thing, not the thing itself. Constraints on Norwegian grammar makes that sentence less clean and idiomatic if the emphasis is properly placed, but in English it works well.

Comment: @WillihamTotland, I think ... I would not move it. "javla" in this context can also mean that it's incredulous that such a thing is found, at all.

Comment: @Lilienthal Well, as I said; translation isn't an exact science. To my ear, as a native speaker of Norwegian, what he says seems to mean "We *found* an alien!" (not "We found an *alien*!", but not having seen the movie, I don't have the full context.

Comment: "The norwegian letter "æ" is pronounced just like the A-sound in "sad" or "handicapped"." The first 'a' in handicapped or the second? ;)

Comment: @Kevin, The a in handicapped that sounds like the a in sad, of course ;)

Comment: What a coincidence the user name is random norwegian guy

Comment: Hah!  I always thought there was a word that sounds a bit like "diabla" in there, and the first thing that came to mind was some variation on "demon" or "devil".  I guess "jævla" fits that bill.

Comment: @Kevin: "The first 'a' in *handicapped* or the second?" Yes. :)

Comment: Interesting how the roots tie in with [Demosthene's Hierarchy of Foreignness](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Hierarchy_of_Foreignness) from the *Ender's* franchise.

Comment: @WillihamTotland I'm a native Norwegian speaker and I think "Fu**ing" should stay where it is in the answer. When you say "et jævla romvesen", the curse word is meant to put emphasis on the object itself, implying that it's amazing or extraordinary.

Comment: @Fiksdal I agree that it's subtle, and probably comes down to taste, dialect or some other factor.

Comment: @WillihamTotland Yeah. To offer some more insight: If Lars wanted to emphasise the act of finding it as special, he could say something like: "Vi har faen meg funnet et romvesen!" ("faen" ultimately means "devil" or "demon" and is also a curse used for emphasis. "Meg" means "me. (I don't know why we say "devil me", lol.) The sentence would be grammatically perfect. He could also have intensified the whole sentence by adding "for helvete" at the end of it. "For helvete" literally means "for hell" and is a strong curse and an "intensifier" of any statement.

Comment: Love that username.

Answer (score 12):

Being a Dane, I am only partly qualified at answering this. But here is my take:

Norwegian (may be a bit off on the spelling):

> Vi har funn et djevelen romvesen

Literally:

> We have found a devil alien

The meaning being more along:

> We have found a fucking alien

The transcription and translation might benefit from the insights of a true Norwegian -- or fjeldabe as we say in Denmark ;). God film for øvrigt...

Comment: Norwegian "romvesen"... homophonic to German "Raumwesen", which would translate to "space being". Sometimes the similarities and differences of the indogermanic languages crack me up. :-D

Comment: Apparently Danes sound like Norwegians speaking with a potato in their mouths ;-)

Comment: The syntax seems a bit weird, we don't really use "djevelen" in that context. Might have a look at the clip when I get back home and see if I can elucidate further on your answer.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how to speak Norwegian, but according to the subtitles, the English translation is:

> We found a fucking alien!  Cheers!

By slightly altering the dialogue to "We *have* found a fucking alien!", we get a Norwegian translation of:

> Vi har funnet en jævla utlending!  Skål!

As I said, I don't know how to speak Norwegian, but this is very similar to what I think I hear in the clip.  I'm not sure about the word "utlending" - it could also be "utenomjordisk" or "romvesen".

Comment: Was it a Mexican alien they found? Otherwise your translation is wrong.

Comment: The thing is that "we get a Norwegian translation" makes it sound like it's a real translation instead of a machine assisted guess. So I think everyone would be happy if that fact was made transparent, like "Google Translate gives us:" or something to that effect.

Comment: @Moyyli I think it's pretty obvious it is a machine translation as he states at the beginning of the answer that he doesn't speak Norwegian

Comment: @WadCheber "I haven't done anything that would require excusing" - except getting the answer wrong ;-) I later got a couple of answers from real Scandinavians, who correctly identified the final word.

Comment: @eirikdaude In my opinion alien is the correct translation. Just because alien can mean different things doesn't it's not the correct word. You know from context what the exact meaning is. By your logic "plant" is not the correct translation of the german word "Pflanze" for example because plant can also mean factory

Comment: @IvoBeckers It was the Norwegian word(s) which were wrong, not the English one.

Comment: @eirikdaude, Aah now I see. I thought you were criticizing the english translation, but now I understand. In that case you're right

Comment: "utlending" would translate to "foreigner", which in this context definitly would seem odd.  "utenomjordisk" would be the adjective or adverb "extra-terestial".  The actual word "romvesen" would most precisely be translated to "space creature" - but of course the correct translation is "alien". (Even though "alien" in english also can mean terrestial foreigners)

Comment: @Moyli - I got the translation from an app, then confirmed it with someone who speaks some Norwegian.

Comment: @randal'thor - Getting a word wrong doesn't mean I need to be excused for anything.

Comment: Just to be explicit about why this is wrong, "utlending" means "from another country", not "extra-terrestrial".  Both of these meanings are covered by the English "alien" but your machine translation picked the wrong meaning.