# Are the English subtitles for The Thing (2011) wrong?

Tags: language-explanation, the-thing-2011

I understand both Norwegian and Danish. The English subtitles for many of the the Norwegian and Danish lines in this movie seem quite off.

For example, "Sitt stille" is subtitled as "Turn on the lights" instead of the correct "Sit still".

What are they really saying?

Comment: My understanding of how movie scripts are written is that the foreign language would be written in English first and then translated later, so you could argue that what is being _said_ is incorrect compared to the intended meaning in the script. I suppose that could open up an explanation: the translator and/or actors decide something else makes more sense and change it, but the subtitlers work from the original script rather than re-translate it back to English.

Comment: @Alan Oh, you mean that the director might have actually wanted to dictate what the subtitles should say, regardless of what the actual Norwegian audio was? (To make it stick more to the original script, or for some other motive?) That could definitely be. The Norwegian audio is full of cursing. I don't recall  any of of that cursing making it into the subtitles. Btw, I have seen two different subtitle versions out there. In several cases they both have the line wrong, but in completely different ways. Sometimes one is wrong and the other is right. I'm about to edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Being a native speaker of Norwegian, I can confirm that yes, the subtitles for many lines are wrong. In a few cases they are actually so bad that the meanings are totally different.

I've made two subtitle (.srt) files where I've replaced the worst ones with my own corrections.

[Download corrected English subtitle file with only Danish and Norwegian lines.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNxi0d0XwrRb3UyTjc4Y1NmZHc/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-Q4Kpfb5Zjz24EO3_wM2sZQ)

[Download corrected English subtitle file with Danish, Norwegian and English lines.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNxi0d0XwrRWHRfMG5fNE9xX1U/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-69JL49AYVMQQokoft4rAIw)

All of Sander's lines are in Danish. Norwegian and Danish are mostly mutually intelligible. I have also received help from the native Danish speaker [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43655/janus-bahs-jacquet) in the comments and from two Danish friends of mine elsewhere.

**Warning 1:** The following answer (quite obviously) contains **spoilers**.

**Warning 2:** This answer contains crude and vulgar language and also parts of an extremely unpleasant, nasty joke by one of the Norwegian characters.

**Note:** The Norwegian characters speak in somewhat different spoken dialects (mostly West Coast Norwegian and Northern Norwegian), but I've transcribed everything in standard, written Norwegian (Bokmål).

I will explain the errors, and what they actually say. I will use the following formatting pattern:

---

00:00:00 (Occasional comment from me.)

> What the subtitle says.

**Transcript of what is *actually* said in Norwegian or Danish.**

*Accurate translation.*

---

I have come across two different subtitles for this movie. One of them only includes subtitles for non-English lines. The other one has subtitles for the English ones as well. Where they differ, I have included both. The one that only translates non-English lines is always (I think) listed first. If you come across any other English subtitles for this movie, please let me know.

### I'll start with the more serious ones:

00:02:16 (This line is much more correct in the other version.)

> Where is it? I don't see anything.

**Hva i helvete er det vi ser etter?**

*What the hell is it that we're looking for?*

---

00:02:22

> I'll let you know when we get there.

There is another, equally wrong, version of this line in the other version:

> A little bit more or else we will be flagged on the site.

**Vi begyner å nærme oss kilden til signalet.**

*We're closing in on the source of the signal.*

---

00:02:37

> You know women...

This line was not spoken at all. The subtitle author must have just made it up or seen it in the original script or something. It's in both versions of the subtitle.

---

00:04:03

> Turn on the lights.

**Sitt stille.**

*Sit still.*

---

00:12:02

> Careful

The other version has a take on this line that doesn't even make sense:

> Brighten

**Sander**

*Sander (He's greeting Sander.)*

---

00:44:35 (This line is in Danish.)

> You made a mistake for bringing these people here. More people may
> die.

**Hør nu hvad jeg siger til dig. Edvard, det er fuldstændig vanvittigt at bringe folk ind i det her udefra. Vi kommer til at miste det vi har fundet.**

*Listen to what I'm telling you. Edvard, it's absolutely insane to bring people into this from the outside. We'll lose what we have found.*

*(Sander is arguing that they should not call for outside help, as that may lose them their sensational discovery of an alien life form.)*

---

00:44:41 (Response to the line directly above.)

> Sander, we do not know even if they are dead.

**Sander, vi er jo langt forbi det punktet nå.**

*But Sander, we have passed that point long ago now.*

*(He's telling Sander that given the dire situation, they should no longer be worrying about the discovery.)*

---

00:56:21

> Let's finish them off!

**Kom igjen, din jævel!**

*Come on, you fucker!*

---

01:05:50

> They escaped.

**De er vekk.**

*They are gone.*

---

01:08:02

> They killed him!

The other version has:

> Lars is killed

**De dreper oss også!**

*They're gonna kill us too!*

---

01:36:38

> Lars, it's me.

**Vær så snill!**

*Please! (Literally: "Be so kind.")*

---

01:37:04

> Do what I say, now!

**Vis meg tenna dine!**

*Show me your teeth!*

---

01:37:07

> It's me Matias. Lars, it's me, Matias.

**Hva faen er det som har skjedd? Lars, hva faen er det som har skjedd?**

*What the fuck has happened? Lars, what the fuck has happened?*

---

01:37:22

> That's no dog. Start the helicopter, now!

**Det er faen ikke mulig. Start det jævla helikopteret nå!**

*It's not fucking possible! Start that damn helicopter now!*

### Here are some relatively minor, inconsequential ones

---

00:01:57

> I remembered a joke.

**Jeg har en bra en her nå.**

*I have a good one here now.*

---

00:01:59

> It's funny.

**Hør den her.**

*Listen to this one.*

---

00:02:02

> A man and his wife were having sex one night...

The other version of the subtitle actually *names* the husband:

> Seorg and his wife were having sex one night,

**Gubben og kjærringa ligger og knuller ut av ville helvete.**

*A man and his wife are in bed, fucking wildly as hell.*

*He uses very vulgar language full of slang, including crude, nearly offensive terms for "husband" and "wife."*

---

00:02:25

> Okay. Continue the joke.

**Ja, gutten og kjærringa, fortsett.**

*Yes, the boy and the woman, go on.*

---

00:02:47

> The boy is on top of his grandmother... Having sex with her!

**Og der ser han faen meg lille Sven ligge oppå farmor. Og bare gir henne jernet!**

*And there, he goddamn sees little Sven on top of his paternal grandmother, just giving her the iron!*

---

00:03:00 (This line is much more correct in  the other version.)

> You play with mine so I play with her, right?

**Det er ikke så artig når det er din egen mor, er det vel?**

*It's not as fun when it's your* **own** *mother, now is it?*

---

00:55:15,

> Let's go Lars, okay?

The other version has:

> Lars, you're okay?

**Lars, vi må komme oss inn.**

*Lars, we have to get ourselves indoors.*

---

01:01:27

> You're next!

**Nå viser du tenna dine!**

*Show your teeth right now!*

---

01:04:48

> She is smart.

**Smart jente.**

*Smart girl.*

---

01:07:45

> Where is Lars?

**Hvor i helvete er Lars?**

*Where the hell is Lars?*

---

01:36:58

> Lars? Lars, it's Matias.

**Lars! Lars, for faen, det er meg, for faen!**

*Lars! Lars, for fuck's sake! It's me, for fuck's sake!*

### The lines not mentioned here, although often not translated very well, are mostly fairly alright.

But I think there were some things that were said in Norwegian and/or Danish that were simply not subtitled at all. I don't want to watch the whole movie again. But if someone gives me the timestamp of such a spoken line, I will edit it into this answer.

Comment: I’ve never seen (or heard of) the film, so I don’t know what the context is, but in Sander’s line in Danish, are you sure he’s really saying, “Ved du hvad? Det er fuldstændig sindssygt…” as two sentences, the first an actual question? Seems a bit odd. Would sound more normal as just, “Ved du hvad, det er fuldstændig sindssygt…”. _Ved du hvad_ is frequently used as simply a pragmatic marker with very little literal meaning. (Also, _det jævla heliktopterer_?!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've listened to it again, and I think you're right. Neither of those were actual questions. Are you Danish, btw? If so, why don't you listen to it and help me make sure it's correct now? Btw, the helicopter thing was a typo, I've corrected it now.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I presume that you are Danish. Here you go, can you help out with this sentence?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtZNpp1V8rI

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey, I noticed you deleted your comments on the question. Is that because the were unnecessary after I made an edit, or was it because you changed your mind regarding the rules of this specific SE? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It sounds like he says “Edvar(d)”, rather than “ved du hvad”—is that the Norwegian guy’s name? Also, “vundet” rather than “fundet”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Great! Btw, how does the meaning of the sentence change when the word is "vundet" rather than "fundet?" (In Norwegian we wouldn't use "vunnet" in that context. ) And as for the rep thing, I think contributors should get some rep from editing. (But that's probably been discussed in meta.)

Comment: @Fiksdal Well, I'm not sure since I don't know the full context. ‘Fundet’ implies physically finding something, while ‘vundet’ here implies perhaps some type of strategic gain or time won or something like that (synonymous, basically, with ‘opnået’). Or that they've won the lottery, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The context is that they've discovered an alien life form frozen in the ice in Antarctica. Sander (the Dane) has been adamant that noone from outside should hear about it, because they may deprive him of the exclusive scientific glory of the discovery. He wants the discovery all to himself. In the current exchange, the alien has woken up to life and killed four people. The Norwegian wants to call for help from the outside. Sander doesn't agree (presumably because he still wants the scientific glory of the discovery). At least that's how I interpret it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: Well, it certainly makes it odd, but I'm pretty sure he says _vundet_. Not sure exactly what he's referring to…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Alright. I'll let your Danish ear override what makes sense in terms of the story.

Comment: @Randal'Thor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-mOy8VUEBk

Comment: I just listened to that bit about 10 times, and I’m now less sure than before. It sounds most like he’s saying an actual IPA [v] (voiced fricative), which is basically halfway between [f] (unvoiced fricative) and [ʋ] (voiced approximant). The Danish /v/ is phonetically a [ʋ], so if he really is saying [v], it could just be a random, accidental voicing of what’s meant to be an /f/. We’d need a script to know for certain, but since _fundet_ does make more sense in context, that is probably what he was meant to say, even if he says it oddly.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the effort. I went with "fundet".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Other people have edited the question again, removing the stuff I added on your recommendation. Just letting you know.

Comment: @Fiksdal ***sigh*** Whatever. I see exactly *zero* point to OrangeDog's edit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I explained your point of view to OD, and OD came up with a compromise (current edit). I'm sure you can discuss it with OD if you want it rolled back to its previous state. I myself really don't have enough experience with SE to have any opinion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I sent the clip to two Danish friends of mine. I don't think they've seen the movie, and I didn't offer them any context at all, I just asked them to transcribe the line. One said "fundet", the other said "vundet". :) I then told each of them that the other one said something else. Haha :) This video comes to mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-mOy8VUEBk

Comment: @Fiksdal At least none of us said _kamelåså_ (which, to be fair, looks and sounds much more Swedish anyway).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Haha. Yeah that's actually true. But now you just ordered a thousand liters of milk.

Comment: Although this may be seen as by some as improper or simply not the proper place, I must. Whilst looking for a complete and accurate Norwegian SRT sub file I found myself marveling at the passion present here on a site which, sadly, I never knew existed before today. Having found more than I was looking for, I signed up to see what else will no doubt blow me away. Before I go I just had to say thank you for the ridiculous amount of work that has gone into these translations and the creation of these free downloadable SRT sub files. Don't worry, next time I'll post any gushing words of gratitude

Comment: @TerribleGoatMedia Thanks, appreciated!